# How to change size attributes JoinJS

Tags: jquery, jointjs

If I have 100 data in attributes. How to change size attributes in JoinJS.
I not sure can use jquery. Help me please.

```
  var uml = joint.shapes.uml;
     var classes = {
            Employee: new uml.Class({
                position: { x: 100, y: 100 },
                size: { width: 200, height: 220 },
                name: 'Employee',
                attributes: ['Surname', 'Salary', 'Permanent', 'HolidayEntitlement', 'StartDate', '...', 'Etc.', 'Surname', 'Salary', 'Permanent', 'HolidayEntitlement', 'StartDate', '...', 'Etc.', 'Surname', 'Salary', 'Permanent', 'HolidayEntitlement', 'StartDate', '...', 'Etc.'],
                methods: [],
                attrs: {
                    '.uml-class-name-rect': classAttrs,
                    '.uml-class-attrs-rect, .uml-class-methods-rect': {
                        fill: 'white',
                        stroke: 'black',
                        'stroke-width': 2,
                    },
                    '.uml-class-attrs-text': {
                        'ref-y': 0.5,
                        'y-alignment': 'middle'
                    }
                }
            }),
        };


        graph.addCells(classes);
```

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with "I have 100 data in attributes. How to change size attributes in JoinJS" ? , please specify a little more your question

Comment: I mean if I have a lot of data. I don't know about resize only center box. Please see image.